# How to use 2 material top tap navigators on one screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add 2 material-top-tab-navigator on one screen in my experiments.
See an example on Snack at the end of this link by docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

Here is my result:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Tab1 = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Updates' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Profile' }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function MyTabs1() {
  return (
    <Tab1.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed1"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
      }}
    >
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Feed1"
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home1' }}
      />
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Notifications1"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Updates1' }}
      />
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Profile1"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Profile1' }}
      />
    </Tab1.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
      <MyTabs1 />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

How can I fix that and use more then one material top tap navigators inside one component or screen?

getting the error:

> Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely
> have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or
> "Screen". Make sure each navigator is under a separate "Screen"
> container. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators for
> a guide on nesting

But expect be able render 2 tabs inside 1 screen correctly. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to React Navigation documents, 1 `<NavigationContainer>` should only contains 1 Navigator (Stack / Tab / Drawer).

So if you need to use multiple navigators, you may need to put that within main navigator.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Tab1 = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="NestedTab"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="NestedTab"
        component={MyTabs1} //Put your another tab here
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Updates' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Profile' }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function MyTabs1() {
  return (
    <Tab1.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed1"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
      }}
    >
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Feed1"
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Home1' }}
      />
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Notifications1"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Updates1' }}
      />
      <Tab1.Screen
        name="Profile1"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Profile1' }}
      />
    </Tab1.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @kiuQ, thanks for this tip. But I have this: 1. I'm using React Native Bottom Sheet component (https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) on my screen where I render top tabs when i click on the button. 2. On the same screen (when bottom sheet is not visible) i want also to render another tabs.

Comment: The solution depends on the bottom sheet is used by whole app or just one screen. If used for whole app, you can put the bottom sheet in `<NavigationContainer>`. Or just for 1 screen, you can put that in `FeedScreen()` or something else.

Comment: This is an example what I want to achieve: [link](https://pastebin.pl/view/1ad30b76)

Comment: and this is my bottomsheet component [popup](https://pastebin.pl/view/2ec15226)

Comment: app screens for reference: [image](https://ibb.co/QQVVQkZ)

Comment: Will the bottom sheet top tab affect the navigation in main screen? or the buttons in bottom sheet only change the content of itself?

Comment: The top tabs in bottom sheet only change the content of itself (text '1' in red on image ). If i close bottom sheet, want to see main screen with it's top tabs (text '2' in red on image ). Trying to achieve that.. but still no success for 2 days.

Comment: Then I would suggest you do not use Material Top Tab within bottom sheet, use [react-native-pager-view](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view) or [react-native-elements/tab](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/tab) instead. It would be easier to implement tab function without another navigation container.

Comment: awesome! thank you for this tip! I will try your links to implement. Btw, how can I rate your comment above?)

Comment: Just press the up arrow (^) next to the comment is fine :)

Comment: i see only the red flag only for this comment.. [screen](https://ibb.co/d4bgvqL)

Comment: You need to have 15 reputation score to use this function.

Comment: Works like expected with [react-native-elements/tab](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/tab) you mentioned. Found also: [react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) and [ant tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs)

Comment: found also this [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view), another issue with react-native-elements/tab is that it doesn't work with scrollable views..

Comment: well, actually,  react-native-elements/tab support scrollable, found [this example](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/3091#issuecomment-865930547), the solution is to wrap your component inside TabView.Item into ScrollView. In my case ScrollView was inside component, and scrolling was not working.